# Get specific word from string in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string, for example:

```
$string = 'username1, username2 and username3 like this posts';
```

I want to get only text contains 'username' and delete everything else. So after delete it will be only **'username1 username2 username3'**.

Comment: Look into regular expressions and captures.

Comment: If your string is "username1aa , username2 and username3 like this posts" what is the expected o/p?

Comment: You can tick the answer if it was really helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `/username\d/g` to match the `username` followed by a digit which will give you the array of matched words then use `join(' ')`, join with a space to get the desired output:

```js
var string = 'username1, username2 and username3 like this posts';

var res = string.match(/username\d+/g).join(' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Minor addition: I'd recommend `/username\d+/g` in case the username has multiple digits at the end

Comment: @MátéSafranka Thanks for suggestion. I added your suggestion in my answer

Answer (score 1):

it will help you to get your character.
var str = 'username1, username2 and username3 like this posts'.replace('username1, username2 and username3 like this posts','username')
    alert(str);